# Extended WPF Toolkit - Change Wizard style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-extended-toolkit

I am working on a WPF application that uses the Wizard window from the Extended WPF Toolkit. I need to **change the color of the footer** of the wizard and unfortunately the developers didn't expose any property to do it, so I need to edit the style.

The Toolkit is imported as NuGet package, so I cannot just edit the source code. I found the default style of the control (Generic.xaml) on [Codeplex](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/Wizard/Themes/Generic.xaml), copied it in a file in my project so now I have something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
                xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Core.Converters">

    <conv:WizardPageButtonVisibilityConverter x:Key="WizardPageButtonVisibilityConverter" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Wizard}">
        ...
```

Here I get two errors:

> The type 'conv:WizardPageButtonVisibilityConverter' was not found.
>   Verify that you are not missing as assembly reference and that all
>   referenced assemblies have been built.

and

> The name "Wizard" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit".

Then I tried to change the line

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
```

to

```
xmlns:local="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

and the second error disappeared, but I don't know how to deal with the first one.

Do you have any idea? Is it the right way to change the default style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAML namespace mapping should also specify the name of the assembly in which the `WizardPageButtonVisibilityConverter` class is defined:

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Core.Converters;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
```